# Can't undelete a closed question because a person who deleted it became a moderator

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderators

While following a "Closed as Duplicate" link I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109997/how-do-you-protect-your-software-from-illegal-distribution).

Should it have been closed as off topic, sure. Did it need to be deleted, absolutely not.

There are 3 undelete votes, however at some point between casting his delete vote and today [Andrew Barber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) became a moderator. Now because of that only another moderator can undelete the question because the system thinks "a moderator has deleted this post and can not be undeleted".

Will a moderator please undelete this question. According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) it should only take 3 votes to undelete and the deleted question says it already has that. My vote which I am trying to cast would actually make it 4.

Comment: The obvious solution is to demote Andrew. I've heard lots of complaints about his heavy-handed moderation and knee-jerk close/delete votes but this is just ridiculous.

Comment: @BoltClock, perhaps you're privy to a view on the history of that question that we mere mortals aren't.  From what I can infer, that question's been around for a *long* time, and it's very much possible that he could have cast a close/delete vote before he became a moderator (there is a window of time of about a month).  Do you know if the system will retroactively mark a newly appointed moderator's close votes as binding?  I'm just throwing out this possibility before the lynch mob comes out, is all.

Comment: @Makoto: The system does not do that with close votes or delete votes. The issue being described here is most likely a bug; I've seen it happen before. Also my first comment was a joke :<

Comment: Well, I wanted to suss out if it was a bug or not.  I half-figured you were kidding around, but people tend to read comments with a diamond on them with a fair bit more seriousness than most.  No big deal. :)

Comment: @Makoto FWIW, I tend to read most diamond comments with at least two tongues in my cheek. Seems more apt most of the time. ;)

Comment: Your second paragraph is contradictory. If it can be usefully answered here, it should be open. Otherwise it should be deleted. It makes no sense to preserve bad answers that can't be improved.

Comment: @Mat My question is to get a moderator to undelete the question.

Comment: @Gilles Please read through the answers in the question. I think the answers are very good quality.

Comment: This could also be considered a bug.

Comment: @Gilles: It is the question that's bad, because it is a poll "What do you use?"  Some of the answers try to generalize that "What solutions are available?"  Other address whether solutions are effective.  Both those topics are adequately addressed in many other questions and answers, such as my [#1 law of software licensing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4532568/103167)

Comment: Likewise I have just come across a post where a person - also a moderator  - answered a question then later on delete his response. I saw the answer as worth retaining so tried to vote for undelete, but no dice given that persons moderator status. For handling their own posts, the moderator powers should be ignored by default.