# Is moderator retirement supposed to affect possibility of undeletion?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, privileges, moderators

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18267668/103167) which was deleted by Bill the Lizard.  Note that I hold him in very high esteem, but this particular case seems questionable; I cannot see anything about the answer that should have triggered a moderator to step in and nuke it.

Because it was deleted by a diamond mod, the behavior of the site is to only let other diamond moderators initiate undeletion.  That appears to have changed when Bill the Lizard retired -- today I was able to cast an undelete vote, just as if it had been originally deleted by community consensus and not unilateral moderator action.

Is this the correct and expected behavior, or a bug?

The opposite situation has also been noted:

- [Can't undelete a closed question because a person who deleted it became a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269513/cant-undelete-a-closed-question-because-a-person-who-deleted-it-became-a-modera)

Comment: I won't go into a lot of detail but that answer and along with several others by that user and a group of users were deleted for promoting one of the websites in that answer.

Comment: As to why that answer was deleted: it was part of a barrage of posts by that user and their coworkers to promote viva64.com , a website plastered with ads for their commercial products. They also engaged in voting fraud to boost the votes for these answers, which led to us removing all of these answers and to warn them strongly about this promotion. Perhaps the self-promotional links could be removed before that was undeleted.

Comment: Ok so @BradLarson will go into the specifics :)

Comment: @BradLarson It seems to me that the post would then become a target for plagiarism flags, seeing as googling the text of the answer brings up the web site that was being promoted.

Comment: @Louis - Yeah, that's a tough one. They wrote the article on their commercial website first, so that they could generate the traffic there with the links here. I hate to reward them for this, but the original source was there. This makes it fun to deal with all the people writing things on their ad-supported Blogspot sites first, then posting them here with "read more here" links back to that. While the attribution is correct, I don't want to encourage this.

Comment: Ahh, voting fraud definitely explains deletion of an otherwise good answer.  The link to viva64 isn't problematic, the relevant information was included directly in the answer and the more comprehensive viva64 post pre-existed this answer by months -- not even the highly questionable practice (although even Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet has done this to my knowledge, and probably many other experts I'm not familiar with) of using a blog to answer (explicitly reply to) a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Louis: Credit would have to be given without including a link (although perhaps just nofollowing, which I think is automatically done on SO anyway, would be enough)

Comment: @BenVoigt I've not made my point clearly. The problem is with people who come across the answer, and find that the answer is word-for-word identical to the text on some web site. From the perspective of such a user, if the text appears without credit and without being properly quoted, then it *looks* like plagiarism. Regarding giving credit, [our page on referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says that giving proper credit "**includ[es] a direct link to it [ie. the source]**" (bold in the original). In cases where credit must be given, then a link is necessary.

Comment: @Louis: It's perfectly reasonable to skip linking to a site that's buried in advertisements, as long as you provide credit in some form and explain why you are not providing a direct link.

Comment: Those guys also spam /r/programming about once a week with a new article about their tool analyzing something. It's pretty blatant.

Comment: @BenVoigt "although even Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet has done this" ... I beg to differ. These two have an extraordinary number of answers. Some of these answers refer to blogposts of their own for **further reading** not for a copy of the very same content. The answers are (from what I have seen to date) always different from the blogpost linked, in the way that they often take direct reference to OP's problem and are written as stand-alone contributions

Comment: @vogel you are attacking a straw man. Read again what I said Lippert and Skeet have done.

Comment: @BenVoigt "not even the highly questionable practice [...] of using a blog to answer [...] a StackOverflow question" -- Yes I am definitely attacking a straw man here. *~cough* If you mean by that, that some of their blog-posts have spawned from SO Q&A ... Why should you care? It's **their blog**. I don't even understand what's "questionable" about that.

Comment: @vogel well I don't think it should be considered questionable (and used those recognized experts to show why it is perfectly OK) but our diamond mods say it is, and will slap you down if you do it more than just occasionally.

Comment: And I was saying that the comparison you're trying to make there is skewed, because of the difference in style of answering...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Note that I hold him in very high esteem, but this particular case seems questionable; I cannot see anything about the answer that should have triggered a moderator to step in and nuke it.

It was deleted because the user has a lot of posts that are just posts that link to their own website.  This is one of those.

**53 out of their 56 answers**, to be precise. You don't see them because they were deleted by multiple moderators.  This answer is another example (one of the better ones) of a post that is promotional in nature (infotainment).

> Is this the correct and expected behavior, or a bug?

Expected. The check is done at the time the action is taken.

Comment: @Kendra The OP stated "Note that I hold him in very high esteem, but this particular case seems questionable; I cannot see anything about the answer that should have triggered a moderator to step in and nuke it." I'm answering that.  I'll add more; but it's important to ensure that there's a trail of why moderator actions were taken.

Comment: The linking doesn't seem excessive, and the answer is not even slightly promotional -- it answers a technical question in a technical way and still more completely than any of the answers that came after.  Voting fraud is a whole different story.

Comment: @BenVoigt Also, keep in mind we explicitly discourage people from using Stack Overflow as a way to promote their website.  If your work is that good, other people will link to it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: it is still astroturfing, however well edited. The user was not here to give their time to answering. Their primary goal was to promote the site.

Comment: I'm with @BenVoigt on this one.  Each answer should be judged individually on its own merits, not the stated, observed, or inferred intent of the person who wrote it.  The answer linked to in the OP contains more information and is a more complete answer than any of the other answers on that page.  Deleting it because it happens to contain a link to 'viva64.com' and was written by someone who likes to link to that site is certainly silly and borders upon absurd.

Comment: Just btw question... Wouldn't removing link (whole first line) and let's say convert the answer to community wiki add more value than nuking it? (from the first look it looks like it provides useful information and that it's "harvest-able" )

Comment: Just out of curiosity: None of the mentioned questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/29646625/1531708) contained a link, not even in the older revisions. Have they been deleted permanently? I didn't know that this is even possible.

Comment: @PhilLab permanent deletion is actually possible, but requires dev involvement and is to my knowledge never done. To my knowledge there was only a single post hard-deleted and that was in the very early stages of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @PhilLab I have captured a [screenshot of that for your reference](http://s11.postimg.org/qmw8ubndf/Screenshot_from_2015_05_13_21_08_44.png). :)

Comment: @aroth You are right, this is just as silly as it would be if Wikipedia deleted content full of valid nutritional information that “happened” to be contributed by Nestlé and link to http://www.nestle.com

Comment: That's so weird to me that past actions taken by a moderator no longer count as moderator actions once they've lost their diamond. It would seem to me that the action itself, upon creation, should be tagged as a moderator action... rather than looking back to the user attached to the action every time. This would have the added benefit of allowing you to place a diamond next to those audit items so you don't lose the context for a particular action, i.e.: "Oh, he was a moderator _at the time_."

Comment: I can understand and sympathize with @BenVoigt's point that an answer should stand on its own and not get deleted because the poster had a pattern of posting other answers for purely self promotion.  But the problem is that when someone does engage in crappy behavior, it is their own fault when even their good stuff gets dismissed.  It is too much to ask of people to put up with crud like that and examine each self serving post, for its own value, in the hopes that one will actually be a decent answer.

Comment: @Gilchrist Oh I agree with the moderators that voting fraud is grounds for deletion no matter how good the answer. It's just difficult for 10k users to know the rationale since no notice accompanies the deletion.

Comment: [Looks like the user has still not learned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26971728) *sigh*

Comment: @BhargavRao Flag the answer. Please.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @George. I have flagged the post.

Comment: @BhargavRao So I looked at the change: between the removal of the author account and the source attribution, it appears the post was edited in a way that violates the Attribution-ShareAlike stack overflow license?  (There are clauses about not removing attribution when editing)  From my layman reading, it appears that editing out "this comes from" may not be allowed by our license, while deleting the post would be.